# Blocking background content and focus on modal dialog

Tags: jquery

I am trying to block the background with my two jquery modal dialogs until the user closes the window. Any idea on how to achieve this?

By "blocking the background" I mean disabling the other elements on the page (i.e. making other elements unclickable).

Here is my code below:

```
            // sign up dialog
        $( "#aboutus_dialog" ).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            show: "fadein",
            hide: "fadeout"
        });

        // sign up dialog
        $( "#signup_dialog" ).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            show: "fadein",
            hide: "fadeout"
        });     

        // about us modal
        $('#aboutus').click(function() { 
            modal: true,
            $("#aboutus_dialog").dialog("open");
            return false;
        });

        // about us modal
        $('#signup').click(function() { 
            $("#signup_dialog").dialog("open");
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Comment: By "block the background" do you mean disable the other elements on the page (i.e. make other elements unclickable)? If so, have you looked at the [`modal` option](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#option-modal)?

Comment: Yes @Colin let me update my question to include that!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal

It does block the background you have the view source button. Do you have any overlay at all?

Try setting it manually(not recommended but rather trough css) :

```
$(".ui-widget-overlay").attr('style','background-color: #000; opacity:1; z-index:1000;');
```

And of course setting the modal option to true.

If the color is too strong decrease the opacity accordingly.

Comment: Thank you so much. How would I apply it to my above code? Where do I set the modal option to be true and set the overlay manually?

Answer (score 4):

when i changed modal value to 'true' (in angular js) all background elements got disabled.here is my code attached:

```
    var options = {
                    autoOpen : false,
                    modal : true,
                    close : function(event, ui) {
                        console.log("Predefined close");
                    }
                 };

    dialogService.open("myDialog" + k, "dialogTemplateload.html", model, options)
    .then(
            function(result) {
                console.log("Close");
                console.log(result);
            },
            function(error) {
                console.log("Cancelled");
            }
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

Look through the dialog options in the API, there are quite a few. In addition to `modal` which sets an overlay over page that blocks mouse events, there is also `closeOnEscape` which if set to `false` doesn't allow user to hit escape key on keyboard to close dialog and therefore has to interact with dialog controls directly

There is a significant API tucked into the tabs on demo page
http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Answer (score 0):

Try creating your own theme using Jquery's theme roller. It also helps in the functionality of the modal and other widgets within Jquery's UI library

http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/

Comment: Under normal circumstances you would be right, link only answers are not appropriate. However,this link is self explanatory, under normal circumstances I would spend a few minutes explaining. It seems redundant  to explain how to use theme roller its very easy to understand. Besides if you look above there a link from jQuery website- comment dated in 2012, this link is still valid. Please don't get mixed up with jQuery being your every day blog where links go missing.