# How to disable clicking on anything other than dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, .net

I've got a `jQuery Dialog`, and would like to disable clicking on anything other than the dialog itself (i.e. no clicking in my ASPX page other than on the dialog). I have searched extensively and not found anything - can this be achieved?

This is my dialog code:

```
$('#controlSettingsForm').dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                width: 'auto',
                maxHeight: 300,
                buttons: {
                    "Save": function () {

                    },
                    "Cancel": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                },
            });

$('#controlSettingsForm').dialog("open");
```

Comment: Duplicate question [Blocking background content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11198086/blocking-background-content-and-focus-on-modal-dialog)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use modal true for overlay:

```
('#controlSettingsForm').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 'auto',
            maxHeight: 300,
            modal:true,
            buttons: {
                "Save": function () {

                },
                "Cancel": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            },
        });

$('#controlSettingsForm').dialog("open");
```

Comment: Thanks - that's just what I was looking for. I wasn't sure what to search for exactly. Looks like modal was the keyword I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

Simply add the parameter `modal: true`:

```
$('#controlSettingsForm').dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                width: 'auto',
                modal: true,              // <---- Add this parameter
                maxHeight: 300,
                buttons: {
                    "Save": function () {

                    },
                    "Cancel": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                },
            });

$('#controlSettingsForm').dialog("open");
```

This will make the dialog appear as "modal". Which means the background will get grayed out and you can't click on it until the dialog is closed.

For more information and examples on the modal parameter check:
http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation

Answer (score 1):

http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal

```
$('#controlSettingsForm').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 'auto',
            maxHeight: 300,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Save": function () {

                },
                "Cancel": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            },
        });

$('#controlSettingsForm').dialog("open");
```

Comment: Thanks - that's just what I was looking for. I wasn't sure what to search for exactly. Looks like modal was the keyword I was looking for :)