# How to make overlay loads automatically above a main window with no close function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, overlay

Could anyone help me for this scenario :

User links to my page -> page loads, but, above, with transparency around, an overlay/or lightbox opens to force user to accept terms & conditions of service or leave. This overlay must prohibit any action (scroll, link...) on the page behind, until user has accepted terms. If he does : overlay disappears and full access to the page is ok, if he refuses, I send him to a "bye bye" page.
I found a lot of autoload overlays and light boxes scripts, but every time, there was a way to close it, or use escape button, or scroll the page behind.
Else, why an "auto load" ? because each page is totally separated from main menu, so I need each page have its own overlay.
Thanks for everyone helping me.

Comment: And [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: I will dismiss/hide your lightbox with e.g. firebug without accepting any terms.

Comment: @Kitet That's motivation! I would close the tab and move on to a different site.

Comment: Anyway, see the [jQuery UI Dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/) plugin. There are *many* alternatives, but I like it because it does a good job of handling focus and is not tied to "image navigation". It can also be trivially configured - such as removing the "X".

Comment: Thanks for reading me. But... how else to prevent a user that he will pay per minute during he is using the document ? I'm obliged to prevent him. Overlay/lightbox is not really fun, but I didn't find other solution.

Comment: You could additionally remove content from underneath and reload page when terms are accepted. Or use AJAX to replace placeholder with actual content.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet to solve this issue would be to use jQuery UI's Dialog Box and more specifically a basic model. (http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal).

I would disable the option to use the X Close button in the right hand corner and provide two buttons in the modal. One for accepting the terms and conditions which closes the modal, the second would be for redirecting the user to the 'bye bye' page.

Sounds like this is a similar request ([Blocking background content and focus on modal dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11198086/blocking-background-content-and-focus-on-modal-dialog))

Cheers!

Comment: Typo, happens to all of us. Hopefully this information helps answer the question for the user.

Comment: thanks again for your help. What's more difficult, is that the access is not a simple "yes-no" alert window. It's a html page containing the I accept - I refuse button, and this is sent by the provider. So, again, I need this page to automatically appear for each document access by auto loading, because I have only 1 button for all pages. I could have made a simple "first page enter the library", but, as the user will pay per minute, I found that it was not justice to let him pay while he was searching the document he wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can define element right after you define body which will have right CSS properties and 2 buttons in middle. If user click on accept you then you close this element, otherwise you redirect.

Code would look something like this.

```
/*CSS*/

#terms{
position:fixed;/*scrolling wont effect it*/
width:100%;
height:100%;
display:block;
background:rgba(set,rgb,a,transparency);
}
<!--HTML-->
<div id="terms">
<input type="button" value="Accept" onclick="document.getElementById('terms').style.display='none'">
<input type="button" value="Decline" onclick="window.location='url'">
</div>
```

This is something in short, you still have to set CSS for this buttons.