# How to stop caching of collection in backbone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js, marionette

I have a very peculiar scenario.

After saving my web page i.e after my POST request is successful, my buttons do not work for the first click.
After having the first click on any part of my web page, my web page starts working fine. Actually, the API calls doesn't happen on the first time. It happens only after the first click. This gives me an error popup, as written in code.

I am using backbone.js, javascript, jQuery, underscore.js, marionette.js, backbone stickit, etc.

So my question is 
1. how to reload my web page so that it redirect to the same page with same tab openings and everything.

```
location.reload(true) or location.reload()
```

takes me to my home page instead of the page I was in.

2. Where to call this reload method, after onRender of that page or immediately after save button has completed its work.

** it seems that the web page looses focus and after having one click at any where on the web page, it brings the focus back.

**EDIT**

I also have an alert message on my web page stating that the changes are successful. Can I possibly create a disabled screen when that alert message comes, and make that screen enable only after first click at anywhere on the screen. If yes, can anyone help me to achieve the same.

**EDIT II**

I went through the whole scenario, debugged till ajax called the API, and I found out that in first click after save, my collection is being cached, and hence ajax never calls the api, whereas in the next click the the cache gets deleted magically, since I don't know yet from where, and the calls goes. So, is there any way I could stop this caching from being done.?

```
   $.ajax= function(options) {
        if ('GET' == options.type) {
            if (false !== options.cache) {
                var url= options.url+'?'+JSON.stringify(options.data); // not the real url, but an incredible simulation
                return readCache[url] || (readCache[url]= oldAjax.apply($, arguments)).fail(function() {
                    delete readCache[url];
                });
            }
        } else {
            readCache= {};
        }
        return oldAjax.apply($, arguments);
    };
```

readcache[url] is true for the fist time, and hence oldAjax.apply never gets called, whereas the second time it is false.

the code is from backbone-extension.js

Comment: what do you mean by "saving my web page"?

Comment: The issue is not with reloading the page actually! There should be a bigger issue which makes the page unresponsive after few clicks.! please figure out the issue and update the question.

Comment: @avck with 'saving my web page' i meant to say that the POST request has been successful. And now I render the page again.

Comment: @DimalChandrasiri : its not after the first few clicks, its only after the POST method, that my first click on the web page has to be for focussing all the elements and from the second click all my elements become responsive.

Comment: Check in browser "Error console" for any errors.
 
The "EDIT" part of your post can easily be achieved by going through this --> http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: This may help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11198086/blocking-background-content-and-focus-on-modal-dialog

Comment: @devd there are no errors on the console.

Comment: can you create a fiddle for this?
also if you have an alert box, only after user clicks on the OK button the focus will comeback to page.
From what you have described it seems the click event binding to button is not happening. If you create a fiddle the flow will be clearer

Comment: You are assuming that reload will solve your problem. But IMHO it won't.
If you have to go down the reload path, you will have to tell what state the app is in. Is there some route for that state? then reload with that state.

Comment: can u share the link to see or one quick think u can do to fix is after completing you can use $(document).trigger('click')... a faster patch ....

Comment: @avck: I cannot create a fiddle and it is a big application, and I myself not sure about what exactly the problem is to recreate. Also, i am not trying to reload, I am just trying to disable the parent screen when the alert comes so that when I click on the disable screen, the alert dismisses and the focus is back on the parent page. Currently, I am assuming since i have a dismissible alert, the alert vanishes, but the focus still remains on the that alert. So , i need to refocus it on the parent basically.

Comment: without knowing the specifics of the stack I can't comment.
But from what you say it looks as a side affect of using alert boxes. Alert boxes have to be dismissed by clicking on it or outside. And then comes the focus to the main(parent) screen. Then what is the problem? You do not want the alert boxes altogether?

Comment: @avck: I have edited the question. Please have a look.

Comment: @DimalChandrasiri please have a look i have edited the question